# Change Google Sheet API from V3 to V4

Tags: php, api, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

This is my code get data from google sheet by sheet name.
I'd like to know when I change my setScopes to down below and it will change API from V3 to V4.

Can someone told me I still need change something or this is OK?

Thank you

```
// Get data from google sheet
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/secretkey.json');
        /*  SEND TO GOOGLE SHEETS */
         $client = new Google_Client;
            try{
                $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
                $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
                $client->setApplicationName("Something to do with my representatives");
                $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']);
               if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
                }

                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()["access_token"];
                ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance(
                    new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken)
                );
               // Get our spreadsheet
                $spreadsheet = (new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService)
                    ->getSpreadsheetFeed()
                    ->getByTitle('xxxxxxx');
                
                // Get the first worksheet (tab)
                $worksheets = $spreadsheet->getWorksheetFeed()->getEntries();
                $arr = array();

                $worksheet = $worksheets[0];
                $listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();
```

```
// Get data from google sheet
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/secretkey.json');
        /*  SEND TO GOOGLE SHEETS */
         $client = new Google_Client;
            try{
                $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
                $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
                $client->setApplicationName("Something to do with my representatives");
                $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']);
               if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
                }

                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()["access_token"];
                ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance(
                    new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken)
                );
               // Get our spreadsheet
                $spreadsheet = (new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService)
                    ->getSpreadsheetFeed()
                    ->getByTitle('xxxxxxx');
                
                // Get the first worksheet (tab)
                $worksheets = $spreadsheet->getWorksheetFeed()->getEntries();
                $arr = array();

                $worksheet = $worksheets[0];
                $listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code below? Also, what library are you using? (if you are using the official one, you can copy [the code from the PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php#step_2_set_up_the_sample)).